# Prove that every invariant spaces of $\varphi'$ is invariant spaces of $\varphi$

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Problem**: Let $E$ be a invariant space of linear operator $\varphi$, $\varphi'$ is a restriction of $\varphi$ on $E'$. Prove that every invariant spaces of $\varphi'$ is invariant spaces of $\varphi$.

**My attempt:** Follows the hypothesis, we have $E' \le E$. $E$ be a invariant space of linear operator $\varphi$ and $\varphi'$ is a restriction of $\varphi$ on $E'$, so $\varphi'(E') = \varphi(E') \subset E \Rightarrow \varphi$ is a linear operator on $E'$. To prove the problem, we just prove $E'$ is an invariant space of $E$. Suppose $S = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ is a base of $E$ and $R = \{x_1, \dots, x_r\}$ is a base of $E'$. Since $E$ is an invariant space with operator $\varphi$ implies $\varphi(R) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ix_i \in E$. Q.E.D

Could you check my work? Thank all!

Comment: "Let $E$ be an invariant space of linear operator $\varphi$". Do you mean $E'$ instead of $E$ here?

Comment: No, $E$ is an invariant space with operator $\varphi$ and from the hypothesis I think that $E'$ is a subspace of $E$.

Comment: I was thinking that $E$ might be the domain of $\varphi$, and $E'$ is the invariant subspace. It's not true that any subspace of an invariant subspace is invariant. Also, simply introducing a new symbol $E'$ without any specification is poor practice when posing a problem.

Comment: @Theo_Bendit You right. But the problem's request here that is: every invariant subspaces of $\varphi'$ also be invariant subspaces of $\varphi$.